# Is there a way to make this user validation code more efficient and/or easier to read?

Tags: java, validation, user-input, do-while

I'm trying to validate the user input such that the program will loop back to the first question of asking the user for the grade if it is NOT an int and the int is not within the ranges of 9 - 12, inclusive. Is there a "better" way of writing this code?

```
do
    {
        if (userGrade < 9 || userGrade > 12)
        {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid grade!");
        }

            System.out.printf("Grade (9-12): ");

        while(!enterInfo.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("That is not a number! Enter in a valid number.");
            enterInfo.next();
        }
        userGrade = enterInfo.nextInt();
    } while (userGrade < 9 || userGrade > 12);
```

Comment: the while condition is repeating itself inside the do block.

Comment: It looks OK, except after reading anything you need to call `enterInfo.nextLine()` to consume the newline from the buffer.

Comment: You can also use a `while (true)` loop and `break;` out of it when the answer is valid.

Comment: It doesn't need to be more efficient. The rate-limiting step here is the user's typing speed, not this code.

Answer (score 1):

To make the code cleaner you can use encapsulation based on classes and
methods (encapsulation is btw the main reason for OOP).

So you divide everything into smaller parts as methods or classes as long as possible, every method has just one simple purpose then. This way the whole program is easier to read, understand and maintain.

Notice for example how the scanner object is just used in the local context of the readInput method.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KillerLoop {

private boolean notReady;
private int grade;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new KillerLoop();

}

/**
 * the default constructor calls the doStuff method
 * which contains the main loop of the program
 */
public KillerLoop() {
    this.notReady = true;
    doStuff();
}

/**
 * the programs main loop
 */
private void doStuff() {
    while (this.notReady) {
        int input = this.readInput();
        this.verifyInput(input);
    }
    System.out.println("Grade " + this.grade + " is a correct grade!");
}

/**
 * verifies a users input
 * if the input is correct, notReady will be set
 * to false so that the programs main loop is left
 * (you could also use an if construct with break for this purpose)
 * @param userGrade the users input
 */
private void verifyInput(int userGrade) {
    if (userGrade < 9 || userGrade > 12) {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid grade!\n" + "Grade (9-12): ");
    } else {
        this.grade = userGrade;
        this.notReady = false;
    }

}

/**
 * this method reads input from the command line
 * and returns an integer if successful
 * @return the users input as integer
 */
private int readInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a grade");

    int userGrade = 0;

    try {
        userGrade = scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("That is not a number! Enter in a valid number.");
        this.readInput(); //this recursion might not always be a good idea ;)
    }
    return userGrade;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I would read System.in and while there is something, first I would try to convert to Integer and then check if that Integer is in correct range:

```
package trial;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            System.out.println("Please introduce a number:");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                String input=sc.next();
                Integer inputInt;
                try{
                    inputInt=Integer.parseInt(input);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("You must introduce a number");
                    continue;
                }
                if(inputInt<9 || inputInt>12){
                    System.out.println("Number must be between 9 and 12 (inclusive)");
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

It is worth noting, because of reading from System.in, this program can be executed from your IDE, so you will have to execute it outside your IDE:

1.-go to TestScan folder and compile it: javac TestScan.java

2.- specify this class in your classpatch to execute it. E.g. if you are in C: you could use something like

C:>java -classpath C:\workspace\StackOverflow\src trial.TestScan

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (userGrade < 9 || userGrade > 12)
    {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid grade!");
    } else {
     do {
        System.out.printf("Grade (9-12):        
        ");

    while(!enterInfo.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.println("That is not a number! Enter in a valid number.");
        enterInfo.next();
    }
    userGrade = enterInfo.nextInt();
} while (userGrade < 9 || userGrade > 12)}
```